# Find biggest contour and apply mask in imageR package

Tags: r, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to find the biggest contour using `imageR` package. I would think the problem is separated in two stages:

1) Find the largest contour
2) Use it for masking the original image

Here's a reproducible example:

```
fpath <- system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager')
im <- load.image(fpath)
```

Perform some random transformation to have a mask

```
binary <- im  %>% 
  grayscale() %>%
  threshold() %>%
  clean(2) %>%
  imager::fill(15)
```

*First problem*:
I could use the `contours` function on the binary image. Turns out that the results are not sorted. So in this case, the biggest contour is the number 5.

```
# find largest contour ?
largest <- as.data.frame(contours(binary)[[5]])
```

```
plot(binary)
lines(largest$x, largest$y, col="cyan", lwd=3)
```

[image]

The package provides a `split_connected` function that could potentially help. It returns a list with the connected masks being each element. However, these are also not sorted by area...

```
li <- split_connected(binary)
# This is the one we want now
li[[2]] %>% plot
```

*Second problem*:
Assuming we had the object, how can we crop the original image and have a segmentation of the largest object (output should be original image dimensions)?

I would expect something like `li[[2]] * im` would be possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have been able to solve this by using

```
  out <- im %>% threshold() %>%
    clean(2) %>%
    imager::fill(15)

  cont_list <- imager::contours(out)

  # polyarea calculates the area of a polygon defined by the vertices with coordinates x and y. 
  # Areas to the left of the vertices are positive, those to the right are counted negative.
  # We can wrap this function
  get_max_area <- function(cont_list){
    purrr::map(cont_list, function(li, x, y) abs(pracma::polyarea(li$x, li$y)))
  }

  areas <- get_max_area(cont_list)
  # get max contour
  biggest <- cont_list[[which.max(areas)]]
```